# Is it possible to have a process running on Heroku for a Facebook app?

Tags: ios, facebook, web-services, mobile, heroku

I'm trying to make a mobile app for Facebook. I'm thinking of having a process running on the Heroku server that will listen for connections from the app that users will run on their iPhones, basically wait there all the time for a signal to do something, and then it can execute tasks on it's own without the user having to load a webpage.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want is a "web service" that the ios code can call without any human interaction.  A web service is like a webpage, but just responds with data.  Kindla like the graph API returns a JSON object for GET requests.

Calling that webservice from ios should be just as easy as the ios SDK does to call into the Graph API.  Check out the opensource ios SDK to see how they're doing it and mimick that in your ios code.

Comment: But how do I even create the web service? How can I start and stop it?

Comment: A web service is JUST like a web site.  It's always running ... waiting for someone to call it ... All you do it change the content response from text/html to text/json or text/xml etc.